# Entity Framework LINQ Multiple Column Count(Distinct)

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm not entirely sure how to translate the following SQL into LINQ Fluent API.  Any help would be great

```
select count(distinct thread.Id) as ThreadCount, count(distinct segment.Id) as SegmentCount
from Segment 
inner join SegmentCommunicator as SegmentCommunicator
    on Segment.Id = SegmentCommunicator.SegmentId
inner join Thread
    on Thread.Id = Segment.ThreadId
where SegmentCommunicator.CommunicatorId in (94, 3540, 6226, 10767, 20945)
```

Currently, I know how to do this in 2 queries but for the life of me I can't figure out how to condense down into one.  Any help would be much appreciated

```
        var aggregate1 = _threadProvider
                .AsQueryable()
                .SelectMany(t => t.Segments)
                .Where(s => s.SegmentCommunicators.Any(sc => communicatorIds.Contains(sc.CommunicatorId)))
                .Select(s => s.ThreadId)
                .Distinct()
                .Count();

        var aggregate2 = _threadProvider
            .AsQueryable()
            .SelectMany(t => t.Segments)
            .Where(s => s.SegmentCommunicators.Any(sc => communicatorIds.Contains(sc.CommunicatorId)))
            .Select(s => s.Id)
            .Distinct()
            .Count();
```

Comment: Thanks Ocelot20, But that produces a list of counts. I want an end result of 2 counts base off of the distinct threadId count and the distinct segmentId

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use one "base" query but the two distinct counts will be separate queries, hydrating the query once with as small of a data set as possible:

```
var query = _threadProvider
            .AsQueryable()
            .SelectMany(t => t.Segments)
            .Where(s => s.SegmentCommunicators.Any(sc => communicatorIds.Contains(sc.CommunicatorId)))
            .Select(s => new {s.ThreadId, s.Id})
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();

var aggregate1 = query.Select(s => s.ThreadId)
                      .Distinct()
                      .Count();

var aggregate2 = query.Select(s => s.Id)
                      .Distinct()
                      .Count();
```

You *might* be able to use `GroupBy` to do it in one query:

```
var query = _threadProvider
            .AsQueryable()
            .SelectMany(t => t.Segments)
            .Where(s => s.SegmentCommunicators.Any(sc => communicatorIds.Contains(sc.CommunicatorId)))
            .GroupBy(s => 1)  
            .Select(g => new 
                {
                    ThreadCount  = g.Select(s => s.ThreadId.Distinct().Count()), 
                    SegmentCount = g.Select(s => s.Id.Distinct().Count()), 
                });
```

but I doubt that the underlying query provider will support it (at best it will turn it into two sub-queries).

Note that neither query will likely perform as fast as the raw SQL, since SQL can optimize the query before returning the results to Linq.

Comment: Thanks D Stanley, I believe that would produce 2 queries to SQL, correct?  Should I assume that I cannot combine this logic into one trip to sql?

Comment: @JonGear Correct.  I should have used `ToList` instead of `AsEnumerable` to execute the query. Fixed.

Comment: @D Stanley GroupBy works, it nets 6 sub queries though, which is less than ideal.  However it's still significantly faster than the first approach of materializing the data in C#. Thanks.  This might be one of those scenarios where just writing the SQL is the better option, unfortunately

Comment: @JonGear Yes, EF is notorious for generating sub-queries.  Luckily it seems that SQL can still optimize it pretty well.  Glad it worked.